# Edit Multiple variables using Single model

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-model

Is there  a way to edit three different variables using just one model? Because in the  current approach it looks like just the variable value is being copied to the "editedVar".

[Fiddle of the code below](http://jsfiddle.net/samsamet/n1rwk8vt/)

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    A: {{A}}<br/> B: {{B}} <br/> C: {{C}}<br/>
    <input ng-model="editedVar"/>
    <br/>
    <button ng-click="switchToA()">Switch to A</button>
    <button ng-click="switchToB()">Switch to B</button>
    <button ng-click="switchToC()">Switch to C</button>
</div>




var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
$scope.A = 1;
$scope.B = 2;
$scope.C = 3;

    $scope.switchToA = function()
    {
        $scope.editedVar = $scope.A;    
    };

    $scope.switchToB = function()
    {
        $scope.editedVar = $scope.B;    
    };

    $scope.switchToC = function()
    {
        $scope.editedVar = $scope.C;    
    };
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? set editedVar to the value of either A, B or C? angular.copy isn't required for value types

Comment: Sorry about that copy I just forget to remove I just removed it. I am trying to change A B C values using the editedVar binded input. Is that possible. The changes in the input should modify the value of A B or C which ever is clicked.

Comment: Can you please update the question. So jjust to be clear, you want the buttons to set A, B & C to the value in editedVar? Why have 3 buttons, why not just have one?

Comment: The edit will be individually not all in once. When you click "Switch to A" the value of "A" should appear in the text box and when you change the value in the text box $scope.A value should change to what you enter in to the text box

Comment: are you trying to update A, B, C by the value `$scope.editedVar` you input?

Comment: Yes thats what it Exactly

Answer (score 3):

You could do it in many ways, here is a simple and more Dry'ier way.

View (Just keep them simple just one function to change the currently edited var):-

```
<input ng-model="editedVar[editing]" />
<br />
<button ng-click="switchTo('A')">Switch to A</button>
<button ng-click="switchTo('B')">Switch to B</button>
<button ng-click="switchTo('C')">Switch to C</button>
```

Controller:-

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    /*Keep the values in an object with respective property name*/
    $scope.editedVar = {
        A: 1,
        B: 2,
        C: 3
    }

    /*Set the default edit property*/
    $scope.editing = 'A';

    /*Sets the currently edited property based on what is being passed in*/    
    $scope.switchTo = function (prop) {
        $scope.editing = prop;
    };

}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7aa5j00u/)**

You could also do it but only with more maintenance code without using an object.

View:-

```
<input ng-model="editedVar" ng-change="valueChange()"/>
<br/>
<button ng-click="switchTo('A')">Switch to A</button>
<button ng-click="switchTo('B')">Switch to B</button>
<button ng-click="switchTo('C')">Switch to C</button>
```

Controller:-

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.A = 1;
    $scope.B = 2;
    $scope.C = 3;

    var editing;
    /*Change event to keep the value in sync*/
    $scope.valueChange = function(){
        $scope[editing] = $scope.editedVar;
    }
    /*Just one function*/
    $scope.switchTo = function (prop) {
        $scope.editedVar = $scope[editing = prop];
    };

}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rg34kuep/)**

Comment: This looks fine for the purpose right. But is there a way to get this work without a object structure. just pass through assigning to each other just as  in my example ?

Comment: @SamSamet Yes you could, it will not let you keep things DRY though and more code to maintain the state. WHy do you need it that way?

Comment: I have a table with hundreds of rows and when a row is clicked I pop up a modal for editing the values. The edit modal is created once and then I need this approach to assign the row object which will be edited.

Comment: In that case best way is to keep them in object, rather than bunch of a lot of primitives. because using object you can always take advantage of object reference. In this case as youtype you need to see the value getting updated in the individual displayed section as well right?

Comment: @SamSamet See my update for more Drier option without using an object

Comment: Actually from @elaijuh 's answer I understood that when you use object assigning it works fine. But assigning variables doesn't reflect the changes. I don't know why but this was what I realized.

Comment: @SamSamet As i said in my previous comment, that is JavaScript basics. When you assign one object to another you are actually cpoying the reference of one to another so ultimately they both point to the same reference location.

Comment: The only thing I can see missing from this solution is that if other code changes the value of the scope properties, `$scope.editedVar` will not be updated correctly. This may or may not be a concern for the OP, though.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a two-way binding of a reference by not primitive type, see below:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    A: {{A.val}}<br/> B: {{B.val}} <br/> C: {{C.val}}<br/>
    <input ng-model="editedVar.val"/>
    <br/>
    <button ng-click="switchToA()">Swithc to A</button>
    <button ng-click="switchToB()">Swithc to B</button>
    <button ng-click="switchToC()">Swithc to C</button>
</div>



var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.A = {val: 1};
    $scope.B = {val: 2};
    $scope.C = {val: 3};

    $scope.switchToA = function()
    {
        $scope.editedVar = $scope.A;    
    };

    $scope.switchToB = function()
    {
        $scope.editedVar = $scope.B;    
    };

    $scope.switchToC = function()
    {
        $scope.editedVar = $scope.C;    
    };
}
```

Comment: Say if OP has 100 of these properties he would have to go create 100 function to switch between them, just saying ?

Comment: in that case, apparently iterating an array is practical

Comment: Yeah or an object, which would be much more easier(like my first approach probably) which would be more explicit than managing based on array index.. IMHO

Comment: and i think the point here is to watch for primitive type or reference :]

Comment: well, that's pretty much depending on OP's business logic and design which i am not intending to judge. just showing the things behind here

Answer (score 1):

The one limitation of @PSL's answer is that if other code changes the value of `A`, `B` or `C` on the scope, `$scope.editedVar` is not updated correctly. Instead, the following alternative uses two watches to ensure the correct scope property is kept up to date, whether because you changed it using `editedVar` in the input, or via some other code.

[Forked jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/greglockwood/fxk3mLux/)

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.A = 1;
  $scope.B = 2;
  $scope.C = 3;

  var propToEdit,
    deregPrevWatch;

  $scope.switchTo = function(prop) {
    propToEdit = prop;
    // set up a watch on this property so if anything else updates it 
    // editedVar gets correctly updated.
    // Make sure to deregister the previous watch first.
    if (deregPrevWatch)
      deregPrevWatch();
    deregPrevWatch = $scope.$watch(prop, function(val) {
      $scope.editedVar = val;
    });
  };

  $scope.$watch('editedVar', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    // skip the initialisation step
    if (newVal !== oldVal)
      $scope[propToEdit] = newVal;
  });

  // start off pointing at A
  $scope.switchTo('A');
});
```

```css
p {
  margin: 2px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.7/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <p>A: {{A}}</p>
    <p>B: {{B}}</p>
    <p>C: {{C}}</p>
    <input ng-model="editedVar" />
    <p>
      <button ng-click="switchTo('A')">Switch to A</button>
      <button ng-click="switchTo('B')">Switch to B</button>
      <button ng-click="switchTo('C')">Switch to C</button>
      <button ng-click="A = 5">Set A to 5</button>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: #1 i hate creating watch unless absolutely needed. #2 what do you mean by `other code changes the value of A, B or C` , You mean dynamically changing yes right but based on what OP said `I have a table with hundreds of rows and when a row is clicked I pop up a modal for editing the values.` i would say this is more like an inline editing feature which does not need it. But this is a good improvement on my initial approach if required.

Comment: #1 Avoiding creating watches is probably a good instinct in the controller code, but Angular creates a lot of watches for you anyway. And I was careful to only have two watches at all times, by deregistering the previous one. #2 See the example of my button to set A to 5. If you click that button while "set to A", the input should update, which only works if you set up a watch on the property being edited.

Comment: ofcourse i know what you are doing, but as i said `unless absolutely needed`... Never know OP original reqmnt might need it in that case ther could be another better design.

Comment: True. In the OP's case of having a table with hundreds of rows, what happens if that data gets an update from the server? If your input should reflect the server data, then you need to somehow know when the data gets refreshed and re-set `$scope.editedVar` to the new value. You could do that with a watch, as I have, or you could add other code to do it only when an update comes in (more efficient, as you are not adding work to be done every digest). Your use of `ng-change` is also a nice way of avoiding having to add a watch on `editedVar`.

Comment: A proper usage of object structure would solve the issue without needing any watch and you dont have some hundred thousand flatout properties on scope.